# Links blocked in scrolling one page site on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, scroll, hyperlink

I have a one page scrolling site width smooth scrolling links. Fixed position nav with links to anchors. Pretty straight forward.

Everything works fine on desktop browsers, but on the iPad (iOS 5 Mobile Safari) links work fine initially, but efter the page gets scrolled (by top nav links), all links including top nav links "get blocked" and can't be clicked. I have to adjust the viewport vertical scroll, then the links works again.

Thankful for any help!

Using this scrolling function:

```
  $('nav ul a').bind('click',function(event){

  var $anchor = $(this);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $( $anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 60
  }, 1200,'easeInOutExpo');

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The same Problem is described here: [anchor links not working properly on ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8601418/1145706)

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198836/1145706

> I've solved this with a trick. I've created invisible divs over the menu items that changes it's position when page scrolls (simulating afixed element over the real position: fixed menu items). When user clicks or hover over those invisble divs the real ones are called