# Issue when using position: fixed for toolbar in iOS 5 (iPad and iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, scroll, css-position

There's an issue when accessing my website (http://www.zero11arquitetura.com.br) on iPad or iPhone with iOS 5 that I can´t fix. When window is scrolled thru code every position:fixed elements click event stop working. Can you please help me ?

This site structure uses a top menu div and a header div with position: fixed css. When user clicks on a menu item window scrolls horizontally until it reaches its target.
Clicking in the menu item is done by jQuery click method on each img tag and scrolling is done by jQuery animate method ($("html:not(:animated),body").animate({ scrollLeft: varDestino }, 1500);)

When page is loaded the menu works just as I intended but, after it scrolls thru menu, and I try to click on another menu item nothing happens. The strangest thing is that everything works again when user manually scrolls the window (by finger).

It looks like that by changing window scroll position by code (jQuery calls window.scroll) fixed elements lost its clickable position references.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you have to reconsider your tags for this question...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but for which ones ? And what to change ?

Comment: I've solved this with a trick.

I've created invisible divs over the menu items that changes it's position when page scrolls (simulating afixed element over the real position: fixed menu items). When user clicks or hover over those invisble divs the real ones are called.

Comment: Please answer your own question, so that this Q&A is useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this with a trick. I've created invisible divs over the menu items that changes it's position when page scrolls (simulating afixed element over the real position: fixed menu items). When user clicks or hover over those invisble divs the real ones are called